# Get photo from facebook profile to user computer (Desktop)

Tags: c#, facebook, desktop

I was wondering if there is any way of only by the profile url (like: www.facebook.com/my.name_123) get the url from the profile picture.
Is a Desktop C# Application... I havent any idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link returns the profile picture:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/{PROFILE_USERNAME_HERE}/picture
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the profile picture you would need to be the persons friend or something like friends friends. In other words, the picture should be visible to you. Or the picture should be public ie. visible to all.
If that is not the problem then try integrating with Facebook API. 
Try:

> http://facebooksdk.net/docs/windows/

and the tutorials there might help you. Let me know if you need any more info. Although I must admit, FB Api is pretty easy to handle.